# Jump to the next step on step timeout in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I would like to skip a step in my Casperjs script when it takes too long to run that step.I used the solution suggested in [(skip step)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20399453/casperjs-skip-step-on-timeout) and I added stepTimeout and onStepTimeout handler. Here is the piece of code for doing that:

```js
var casper = require("casper").create({
  verbose: true,
  stepTimeout: 10000,
  pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,
    loadPlugins: false,
    ignoreSslErrors: true,
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.2 Safari/537.36'
  },
  onStepTimeout: function() {
    this.echo("Step " + this.step + "timed out ");
    this.echo("Step .page" + this.step.page + "---- ");
    this.clear();
    this.page.stop();

  }

});
```

The rest of the code simply opens a list of URLs. The problem is that for some cases such as opening this URL [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/?hl=en), when it takes longer than the specified timeout to open it, onStepTimeout event is fired but the value of this.page is undefined. So it results in crashing phantomjs(with segmentation fault).

I couldn't find any other solution to skip the current step and continue with the next step. Is there any other way to do ? any other suggestions?!

Comment: Does `this.mainPage.stop()` work for you?

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work either. Anyway thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you want to reproduce it, [here](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/1129) is a piece of code with the same issue sent by my friend on Casperjs issues.

Answer (score 0):

[New in version `1.1`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#bypass)
Bypasses a given number of defined navigation steps:
`this.bypass();`

```
onStepTimeout: function(){
  this.bypass(1);
}
```